# Basic threading, interleaving threads confusion?

Tags: multithreading, haskell

I am slightly confused by the interleave function given in [this](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html) guide.

I have the following data type:

```
data M m r = Atomic (m (M m r)) | Done r
```

I've created a lifting function to take a `m a`, inserts the `a` inside `Done`, and then re-inserts `Done a` back into `m ()`. This forms the `Atomic` structure:

```
atm :: Monad m => m a -> M m a
atm m = Atomic $ liftM Done m
```

I've made `M m` an instance of the `Monad` class (which pattern matches based on data constructor):

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (M m) where
   return = Done
   (Atomic m) >>= f = Atomic liftM (>>= f) m
   (Done r) >>= f = f v
```

There's a simple implementation function which accesses nested values within the `Atomic wrapper`:

```
runThread :: Monad m => M m a -> m a
runThread (Atomic m) = m >>= runThread --Extract m and recursively pass to runThread
runThread (Done r) = return r --Return Done
```

Then, there is the following interleave function:

```
interleave :: Monad m => M m r -> M m r -> M m r
interleave (Atomic m1) (Atomic m2) = do
   next1 <- atm m1 --? 
   next2 <- atm m2 --? 
interleave next1 next2
interleave (Done _) t2 = interleave t2
interleave t1 (Done _) = interleave t1
```

My points of confusion are at `next1 <- atm m1` and `next2 <- atm m2`.

**As I understand it, all this is doing is taking `m1` from the `(Atomic m1)` wrapper and reinserting it back into an `Atomic` wrapper? How is this operation interleaving?**

Am I missing something basic here? The code works fine, so I'm sure it's due to my confusion.

The rest of the code:

```
threadOne :: M IO ()
threadOne = do 
  atm $ print 1

threadTwo :: M IO ()
threadTwo = do
  atm $ print 2

main = do
  runThread (interleave threadOne threadTwo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are partially right. The code

```
next1 <- atm m1
```

takes the atomic action that the first thread starts with and inserts it into the merged/interleaved thread. What's returned from the call to `atm` is the continuation `next1` of that first thread.

But next, we are taking an action from the second thread, by saying

```
next2 <- atm m2
```

So the merged thread ends up executing an action from the first thread, and then one from the second thread. Hence "interleaving". We then continue by calling `interleave` recursively on the two continuations via

```
interleave next1 next2
```